# Lookup data based on a date that falls between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to sheets within a workbook.  On sheet 1 I there is a date that is the LOOKUP criteria(cell B9).  I need to look in Sheet 2 and if the falls between the dates in Columns A and C...if so, then lookup the info in columns D thru K and populate the cells (E10 thru E16) on sheet 1.

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

I currently used the following formula in cell E10 in sheet 1...

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((DATEVALUE($B$9)>='AUSSIE Wkly'!$A$3:$A$500)*(DATEVALUE($B$9)<='AUSSIE Wkly'!$C$3:$C$500))
```

But nothing comes up as you can see.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you want to retrieve values in row 4.
In Sheet1, cells E10, E11 you would use

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$3:$D$500,SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$A$3:$A$500<=Sheet1!B9)*(Sheet1!B9<=Sheet2!$C$3:$C$500)*(ROW(Sheet2!$A$3:$A$500)-ROW(Sheet2!$A$3))))

=INDEX(Sheet2!$E$3:$E$500,SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$A$3:$A$500<=Sheet1!B9)*(Sheet1!B9<=Sheet2!$C$3:$C$500)*(ROW(Sheet2!$A$3:$A$500)-ROW(Sheet2!$A$3))))
```

You could put together similar formulas for the other cells.

I take the opportunity to **stress the power of `SUMPRODUCT`**, quite often more flexible and comprehensive than: 1) Array formulas, 2) Lookups, 3) `COUNTIFS`, 4) `SUMIFS`.

I am leaving here for those interested a few links showing that.

1. Better than `COUNTIFS`

   [COUNTIFS with ISNUMBER and multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050958/countifs-with-isnumber-and-multiple-criteria/47051081#47051081)

   [Have COUNTIFS ignore all blank cells (= empty cells and cells containing "")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291888/have-countifs-ignore-all-blank-cells-empty-cells-and-cells-containing#comment46793208_29293896)
2. Multiple lookups

   [Searching an excel with two search words (multiple lookup) using vba macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576595/searching-an-excel-with-two-search-words-multiple-lookup-using-vba-macro/21582535#21582535)

   [Multiple-column based lookups in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965329/multiple-column-based-lookups-in-excel/21738261#21738261)

   [Finding rows with multiple values in the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761930/finding-rows-with-multiple-values-in-the-columns/20762471#20762471)
3. On two questions related to yours

   [Excel: Counting how many rows fall within a time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780136/excel-counting-how-many-rows-fall-within-a-time-period/27780657#27780657)

   [How to calculate results and plot data depending on results of a specific column in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767231/how-to-calculate-results-and-plot-data-depending-on-results-of-a-specific-column/30772648#30772648)

(and you are welcome [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2707864%20%5Bexcel%5D%20sumproduct), which shows I am actually "fond of" `SUMPRODUCT`).

Comment: I apologize...but you lost me.  What I am trying to do is for me to use the date in B9 on sheet 1 LOOKUP in sheet 2 to see IF the date falls between the date in Column A and C, if so then return the value/content in column D,E, F and so on to display that data on Sheet 1 in cells E10 -E16 correspondingly.  Sorry ..I'm lost lol.

Comment: @DBrown - I had inverted the roles of Sheet1 and Sheet2. I have now fixed that.
At any rate, I guess the idea is clear.